# Reduce length of twitter feeds using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Hi I'm using Twitter Post Fetcher v11.0, which can be seen in this link here
http://codepen.io/heathriel/pen/Gsdkm
I'm trying to reduce the length of each twitter post, extracted from this jQuery plugin, and then add an ellipsis so for example it should be like :

twitter post : xxxxxxxxxx...

where the original tweet would of been this:

twiiter post : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Therefore reducing the characters of the tweet, and then add an ellipsis. 
I thought there may be a way in the handleTweets function of the code, which is shown here:

```
function handleTweets(tweets) {
    if (customCallbackFunction === null) {
        var x = tweets.length;
        var n = 0;
        var element = document.getElementById(domNode);
        var html = '<div>';
        while (n < x) {
            html += '<div>' + tweets[n] + '</div>';
            n++;
        }
        html += '</div>';
        element.innerHTML = html;
    } else {
        customCallbackFunction(tweets);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If you just want to know if it is possible to do this with the sources you provided, then yes. Absolutely. You only need to parse through the DOM elements of each element in the `tweets[]` array.

Comment: Ive updated the question hopefully it should be clear

Comment: It is still unclear what your question is. What have you tried? Where are you stuck and need assistance?

Comment: Ive tried to figure out the length of `tweets[n].length` and then manually trying to reduce the length but that doesn't seem to work for instance, `tweets[n].length = 20`

Comment: Yes, because `tweets[]` is an array, which contains other DOM elements itself. You could see this on the site you posted, if you utilize your browser's developer console. For instance in Firefox right click on the twitter output text, select "Inspect". There you see that `tweets[n]` is another DOM tree, which contains `P`- and `A`-tags.